# Python Swap Function

Tags: python, list, swap

I'm having a hard time expressing this in Python.

This is the description of what needs to be done.

> swap_cards: (list of int, int) -> NoneType
>
> ```
> swap_cards([3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0], 5)
> [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6]
>
> swap_cards([3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0], 6)
> [0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3]`
> ```

I've created 2 examples, but I don't know how to start the body of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like some index notation is required here:

```
>>> def swap_cards(L, n):
...     if len(L) == n + 1:
...         L[n], L[0] = L[0], L[n]
...         return L
...     L[n], L[n+1] = L[n+1], L[n]
...     return L
... 
>>> swap_cards([3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0], 5)
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6]
>>> swap_cards([3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0], 6)
[0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3]
```

Comment: if it's a nonetype function, is 'return' allowed to be written in the body? (sorry I'm a new programmer)

Comment: @sarah I'm not sure what you mean by a "NoneType" function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tuple swap idiom `a, b = b, a`to swap the variable noting that for edge cases you need to wrap around the index `index % len(seq)`

**Implementation**

```
def swap_cards(seq, index):
    indexes = (index, (index + 1)% len(seq))
    seq[indexes[0]], seq[indexes[1]] = seq[indexes[1]], seq[indexes[0]]
    return seq
```

**Example**

```
>>> swap_cards([3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0], 6)
[0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3]
>>> swap_cards([3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0], 5)
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap_cards(deck, index):
    if index in range(0, len(deck)):
        factor = (index + 1) % len(deck)
        aux = deck[factor]
        deck[factor] = deck[index]
        deck[index] = aux
        return deck
    else:
        return None

deck = [3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 0]

new_deck = swap_cards(deck, 6)

print new_deck
```

Output:

```
[0, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3]
```